# How to get the json-serialized object tree without encoding and decoding again

Tags: php, json, serialization

If I have an object tree of objects implementing the `jsonSerializable` interface, I can do

```
$serializeableData = json_decode(json_encode($objectTree), true);
```

to convert the object tree into an array structure. Is there some concise, more performant way to convert the object tree?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "convert the object tree into an array structure" exactly. For a simple object-to-array conversion it can't get simpler than that. And it also depends on the reason why you can't work with the object tree directly.

Comment: @Dormilich I'm wondering if `serializeableData` has a hint, that its less space to `serialize()` an array, than an object... but... that then begs the question of why use serialize, when you already have the very clean and trim json ;)